# How to do numpy combined slicing and array indexing with unknown array dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, scipy

I have a list of index tuples for all dimensions of an array bar the first two.

For each index tuple, I would like to return a slice of the array at this tuple position.

I don't know in advance the number of dimensions in the array, or equivalently the number of elements in the index tuple.

For example, if there were two elements in the index tuple (`pos`) I would write something like:

```
arr[:, :, pos[0], pos[1]]
```

to return a slice of the array at this position. I would like to be able to do this without knowing in advance the length of pos. Naively, I thought `arr[:, :, *pos]` would work, but of course it doesn't.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are the elements of index integers or a lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the `Ellipsis` with your tuple `p`, to obtain the tuple `Ep` that can be used to slice the array:

```
Ep = (Ellipsis,)+p
sliced_arr = arr[Ep]
```

Edit: kudos to the previous answer (which has been deleted) for mentioning the `Ellipsis`, which is really half of my answer here.

Comment: This is much smarter than what I was trying to do

Comment: `*` expansion does work inside a tuple, e.g. `arr[(Ellipsis, *p)]`.